# FF Addon (JPM) Pass message from Panel's script to main index script

Tags: javascript, message, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I am developing a FireFox extension using JPM Addon. I am loading a panel from the main index.js file like so...

```
var panel = require('sdk/panel');
var panel = panel.Panel({
    contentURL: url('pages/popup.html'),
    onHide: doHide
});

//and in another place...
panel.show({
            position: button
        });
```

The pages/popup.html file references a javascript file and I use the relative path to load it. I need to figure out how to pass a message from this javascript file, loaded by the panel web page, to the main index.js script file of the addon.

I tried postMessage as well as port.emit...

So, either

```
//index.js
panel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
  onMessage: function(message) {
    console.log(message);
  }
});

//popup.js - panel file
panel.postMessage('something');
```

...or...

```
//index.js
panel.on("message", function(text) {
  console.log(text);
});

//popup.js
self.port.emit('message', 'hello world');
```

However, both of these don't seem to work. Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read the section "[Scripting trusted panel content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Scripting_trusted_panel_content)" in the [MDN sdk/panel page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel).  The most relevant text is:

> Like a content script, these scripts can communicate with the add-on code using the [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/using_postMessage) API or the [`port`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/using_port) API. The crucial difference is that these scripts access the `postMessage` and `port` objects through the `addon` object, whereas content scripts access them through the `self` object.

So, your *popup.js* code should be:

```
addon.port.emit('message', 'hello world');
```

And your *index.js*:

```
panel.port.on("message", function(text) {
  console.log(text);
});
```

There is an example add-on in the "[Scripting trusted panel content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/panel#Scripting_trusted_panel_content)" section showing communication in both directions between the trusted panel (panel content comes from within the add-on) and the main background script of the add-on.

Comment: Is it possible to call a function from the addon script as well? In reality, I am porting a Chrome extension and cannot use callback for what I need.

Comment: @ShahidThaika, Message passing is asynchronous (potentially from one process to another). This is true in Chrome also. If you mean a synchronous function to *send* a message from the add-on script, then yes. For the above code, that would be `panel.port.emit(nameOfMessage,message);`.  BTW: If you are porting a Chrome extension and you have not already done so, you may want to take a look at the [WebExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) API, which is very similar to Chrome extensions.

Comment: I used a function in the panel to return a string based on the browser's localization. However, in FF it seems you need to use require('sdk/l10n').get, which is only accessible through the index.js file. I need to figure out how to call the localization function.

Comment: Hi @Makyen, I would like to know how to pass message form panels script to content script?

Comment: @vivek, That sounds like it should be a new question :-). It would help to have a bit more context than just that short description (thus the new question). Do you have code that you have already tried? You probably have to go panel script ⟷background script⟷content script. how to structure that will depend a bit on what you are attempting to do/communicate and how complex your add-on is (e.g. how many content scripts & panel scripts).

Comment: @Makyen Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39241698/firefox-addonjpm-how-to-pass-message-from-panels-script-to-content-script